# How to check if CSS is on an element?

Tags: css

Was getting into CSS and web development and I have seen some sites that have example a submit button or just an input where when the mouse/ cursor goes over the top of the element it would change the element,

To explain a bit better, the submit button might be red and black text, and if you hover over the submit button it would go black and change to red text,

I just wanted to know how that was done cause I would like to put that on my sites, thanks!

I have searched google alot for information on how to do this but I have come up with nothing, best regards,
Jack.

Comment: use the `:hover` pseudo-selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:hover` selector. See the following examples, how to do that:

```css
button,
input[type="submit"] {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#f00;
}
button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color:#f00;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
<input type="submit" value="Test"/>
```